# Sharing a class between multiple classes

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, static

I have a class called `Manager` and another class called `EmployeeFileHandler` which inherits from `IFileHandler`.

I wish to create a new class `EmployeeInfo` which I will be able to access from both the `Manager` and the `EmployeeFileHandler` in a `static-way`. However, from what I know, the `static` keyword cannot be applied on inheriting/ed classes.

Can this be done in any way?

Comment: Does your EmployeeFileHandler have to be static?

Comment: No, I meant that `EmployeeInfo` would be static, not `EmployeeFileHandler`

Answer (score 3):

Since C# does not support multiple inheritance, you can do it by either:

1. Having both instances for your `EmployeeInfo` (`has a` relationship, instead of `is a` relationship).

   ```
   public class EmployeeInfo {
       public static Manager Manager = new Manager();
       public static EmployeeFileHandler EmployeeFileHandler = new EmployeeFileHandler();
   }
   ```

   Thus, whenever you need to access `Manager` class methods, you use `Manager` instance and whenever you need to access `EmployeeFileHandler` methods, you use `EmployeeFileHandler` instance.
2. Or, alternatively, you could create the `EmployeeInfo` to inherit from `Manager` and implement interface of `IFileHandler`

   ```
   public class EmployeeInfo : Manager, IFileHandler
   ```

   This is ok, provided that `EmployeeFileHandler` does not have extra methods as compared to `IFileHandler`

Comment: what do you mean by saying "has a relationship, instead of is a relationship"? Could you please explain?

Comment: Has a relationship means it is not derived from that class, but having that class nevertheless. For instance. Bob is a Man, thus it has all Man's methods. But Bob has a Scissors, that means he can use Scissors to do what he wants to. One (is a) means you inherit from, but another (Has a) means you have it. In the C#, it looks pretty differently, check out my examples

Comment: in your first option, it's just like placing the `EmployeeFileHandler` under the `Manger` then, isn't it? My `Manager` is my `ViewModel`. In this class I would like to create/edit the `EmployeeInfo` and then use the `EmployeeFileHandler` to write to/load from a file the `EmployeeInfo` - the thing is that I would like to create a separation. I don't want the data to be mixed with either the `ViewModel` or the `FileHandler`.

Comment: @Idanis In my first option, actually I am placing `EmployeeFileHandler ` under `EmployeeInfo` not under `Manager`. But if you need `EmployeeInfo` to be of `class` `Manager`, then you may consider to use both cases I show partially to: `EmployeeInfo : Manager` but you have a field for `EmployeeFileHandler`